# Firebase Cloud Function - Push a notification to iOS device when document is added to firestore

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I have been reading multiple articles and stack overflow posts on how to send a push notification. I have tried using collection listeners on my firestore collection, but it ends up sending notifications for all documents when the app closes. Then, I've tried firebase cloud functions and there always seems to be an error, even though I've taken it from a medium or stack overflow post and modified it to my database.

Every time I run $firebase deploy in the terminal, I get this error:

```
20:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token body

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/g30r93g/.npm/_logs/2018-07-10T00_28_45_371Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
const functions = required('firebase-functions');
const admin = required('firebase-admin');

// initializes your application
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.firestore
 .document("Users/{user-ID}/sub-Collection/{sub-Document-ID}")
 .onCreate((events) => {

// Access data required for payload notification
const data = event.data.data();
const senderName = data.storeName;

// Determine the message
const payload = {
  notification: {
  title: "New Document"
  body: "Tap me to show new document"
  sound: 'default'
  badge: '1'
 }
}

// Get the user's tokenID
var pushToken = "";
return functions
.firestore
  .collection("Users/{user-ID}")
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    pushToken = doc.data().tokenID;
    // Send the message to the device
    return admin.messaging().sendTodevice(pushToken, message)
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written invalid JavaScript.  Your `payload` object needs its fields and values separated by commas:

```
// Determine the message
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "New Document",
    body: "Tap me to show new document",
    sound: 'default',
    badge: '1'
  }
}
```

Note the trailing commas.

The error message was "Parsing error: Unexpected token body".  It was complaining specifically that it found the "body" field unexpectedly, which would have been your clue what it got hung up on.

Comment: ahhhhhh  stupid me. I also needed to convert the first two lines of code to import statements. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have used typescript to do this. Here is the final code for anyone else that is looking to implement this in their project:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// initializes your application
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.firestore
 .document("Users/{user-ID}/sub-Collection/{sub-Document-ID}")
 .onCreate((events) => {

  // Access data required for payload notification
  const data = event.data.data();
  const senderName = data.name;

  // Determine the message
  const message = {
    notification: {
    title: "New Document",
    body: "Tap me to show new document",
    sound: 'default',
    badge: '1'
   }
  }

  // Get the user's tokenID
  var pushToken = "";
  return functions
  .firestore
   .collection("Users/{user-ID}")
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      pushToken = doc.data().tokenID;
      // Send the message to the device
      return admin.messaging().sendTodevice(pushToken, message)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax that worked for me.

```
exports.sendExpNotifications = functions.firestore
      .document('sandwiches/{sandwich}')
      .onCreate((docSnapshot , context) => {

            // Access data required for payload notification
            const experience = docSnapshot.data();
            const senderName = experience.senderDisplayName
            const recipID = experience.recipID

            return admin.firestore().doc('users/' + recipID).get().then(userDoc =>{
                const token = userDoc.get('token')
             console.log(token)
                const payload = {
                    notification : {
                        title : senderName + " sent you a message.",
                        body : "notificationBody"
                    }

                }

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload);
              })
      });
```